# How do I style my pie-chart like this?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, pie-chart

[image]

---

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/KQ93N/)

---

My code so far:

```
var data = [
    {
        "mood": "Joy",
        "value": 400
    },
    {
        "mood": "Worry",
        "value": 100
    },
    {
        "mood": "Anger",
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "mood": "Sadness",
        "value": 100
    },
    {
        "mood": "Frustration",
        "value": 200
    },
    {
        "mood": "Hope",
        "value": 300
    },
    {
        "mood": "Admiration",
        "value": 100
    }
];

var width = 400,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 10)
.innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
});

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.mood); });

g.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) { return d.data.mood; });

//});
```

Comment: The example data you provided only has one dimension; for this visualization to be meaningful (which is hard: this sort of area comparison is not easy for people) there needs to be a second dimension to plot.

Comment: If you mean the second dimension as the width of the pie, that could be random.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://kreese.net/blog/2012/08/26/d3-js-creating-a-polar-area-diagram-radial-bar-chart/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That tutorial webpage is giving me Error 403.

Comment: Works for me. Firewall settings?